# How to reset a dictionary for every one hour

Tags: python, dictionary, time

Is it possible to reset python dictionary in every one hour?

Original dictionary:

```
d = {1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 2}
```

For every one hour the dictionary should be empty (or new dictionary should be created)

```
d = {}
```

But the program below  is not working

```
import time 
d = {}

d[1] = 5
d[2] = 1
d[3] = 2
i = 1
while i == 1:

    current = time.time()

    end = time.time()
    diff = end - current
    if diff == 60:
        d = {}
    print d
```

Comment: You calculate `current` and `end` *in the same loop*. They'll never differ more than a small fraction of a second.

Comment: Why do you expect the difference between `end` and `current` to increase on each iteration of your loop? \

Comment: You cannot let a program continuously test the time difference, its a huge waste of processing time. Threading and sleeping is a better option. simply make a separate thread, let it sleep for an hour, then wake up to change the dict.

Answer (score 2):

```
import time, threading
d = {1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 2}
def updates_dict():
    d = {}
    print "Updated on",time.ctime()
    threading.Timer(10*60*60, foo).start()

updates_dict()
```

You can implement with using `threading`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

d = {1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 2}
start = time.time()
while True:
    diff = time.time() - start
    if not round(diff) % 60:
        d = {}
    print d
```

Comment: Think of it, a loop continuously running for an hour. Better to use threading and sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at [the APScheduler module](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It has a lot of options for timed events.